# `allowsMultipleSelection: true` throws error in expo-image-picker (expo SDK 46)

Tags: typescript, react-native, image, upload, expo

I have no problem selecting one image at a time with `allowsMultipleSelection: false`. But with `allowsMultipleSelection: true`, it throws an error.
Note: I do have `allowsEditing: false`.

**What's happening**

I get this error: `"code":"ERR_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"Cannot handle 'public.jpeg' media type"`
Not sure where 'public.jpeg' comes from as I am selecting, from my IPhone simulator (iOS 15.5), different types of pictures from different albums, and the error is the same for any picture I select.
I do **not** have this error when `allowsMultipleSelection: false`.

**Context:** 
React 18 
Expo SDK 46
Expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
iOS 15.5 Iphone Simulator
Typescript: 4.8.2

**Things I've tried**

- I ran `expo doctor`to check if dependencies problems but there are none.
- Tried adding other options such as `base64: true`, different qualities, etc
- Note: when I opened the `node_modules` folder, at `expo-image-picker/plugin/tsconfig.json`, this line was erroring: `"extends": "expo-module-scripts/tsconfig.base"` as the file was not found. So I manually installed `expo-module-scripts` and now the error is gone, with the line `"extends": "expo-module-scripts/tsconfig.plugin"` generated instead.
  The above did not change anything though - I get the same error on selecting multiple images (`ERR_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE`).

**Packages:**

#### Minimal reproducible example

```
import React from 'react'
import { launchImageLibraryAsync, MediaTypeOptions } from 'expo-image-picker'
import { View, Button } from 'react-native'

export function GalleryImagesForm(props) {
  const pickImages = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    try {
      let result = await launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsMultipleSelection: true,
      })

      console.log(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImages} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I just  tested this and if you remove mediaTypes the error goes away. The only reason I can think of this happening is that  jpeg an have .jpeg and .jpg as the file type and maybe `MediaTypeOptions.All` only covers one of those?

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, that's interesting - I removed it and I still have the error, only, the extension on the error message changes:  `Cannot handle 'public.jpeg' media type` to `Cannot handle 'public.png' media type` :/ (and different pictures pics have that message with their extension )